# Generalizing/looping conditional cumulative sum algorithm across multiple columns in R

Tags: r, cumsum

I have found a lot of questions and answers regarding conditional cumulative sums in R, but so far, all the ones I have seen involve conditionally summing a single variable.

What I am trying to do is generalize the conditional sum formula so that it can be looped across multiple columns. I have a huge data frame (approximately 2500 rows by 136 columns) containing historical NFL game data. There are 16 rows per team-season and roughly 130 variables per game.

I want to calculate a running week-by-week (year-to-date) cumulative mean of each statistical category for the ultimate purpose of calculating each team's weekly z-score with respect to the league as a whole.

Here is an example using the `ddply` package that accomplishes this task for a single variable (in this case offensive second-quarter scoring):

```
ddply(test.data, "TeamSeason", transform, Cum.Mean = cumsum(O2QPt) / Week)
```

How can I loop through all of statistical category columns without using a `for` loop? If I must use a `for` loop, is there a way to reference the columns by numerical ID rather than by label?

---

The following code gets me very close to where I want to go. Kudos to **Max Ghenis** for pointing me in the right direction.

```
testdata.dt[order(UGID)][, lapply(.SD, cumsum), by="TeamSeason", .SDcols=numerics]
```

However, although the data is listed in proper UGID (unique game ID) order, the UGID values are not output. How can I include this column in the output so that I can keep track of the game IDs in my table?

Comment: You have not described the features of the "conditionality". Define what "each statistical category" means by offering code.

Comment: I just now noticed this comment. I come from an imperative programming background, which is one of the reasons I am struggling with this. Would For loops better describe the conditionality?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the `data.table` package, since you can use `lapply` to perform the same function across multiple variables in a single step. Here's an example:

```
mtcars.dt <- data.table(mtcars)
# Grab cumsum of mpg only
mtcars.dt[, cumsum(mpg)]
# cumsum of mpg and hp
mtcars.dt[, lapply(.SD, cumsum), .SDcols=c("mpg", "hp")]
# cumsum of mpg and hp, ordered by mpg and split by cyl
mtcars.dt[order(mpg)][, lapply(.SD, cumsum), by="cyl", .SDcols=c("mpg", "hp")]

# Omitting .SDcols results in cumsum of all columns
mtcars.dt[, lapply(.SD, cumsum)]
# Nonnumeric columns cause issues though, e.g.:
mtcars.dt[, dummy.text:="text"] # Add character column
mtcars.dt[, lapply(.SD, cumsum)] # Warning, but would be error with sum
# Solution 1: Remove the column
mtcars.dt[, !c("dummy.text"), with=F][, lapply(.SD, cumsum)]
# Solution 2: Specify .SDcols as all numeric columns
numerics <- which(sapply(mtcars.dt, is.numeric))
mtcars.dt[, lapply(.SD, cumsum), .SDcols=numerics]
```

Comment: I appreciate your prompt answer. Am I to understand that I have to explicitly name all the variables to which I want to apply the function? Is there no way to simply tell the function to apply itself to all of the columns?

Comment: You can omit the .SDcols argument to do this; answer edited to give some options.

Comment: I apologize for the slow response. I am working on this project in my free time. I worked through the example you gave and what I want to do seems to be a hybrid of the two scenarios. To use your terminology, I want to cumsum *all* (subsequent) columns in the mtcars data set ordered by mpg and split by cyl. If this is not clear, I can provide some sample data that might clarify the situation. I appreciate your patience as I grapple with this.